# Div\label\Span disappears after timer event finishes firing

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I'm building a webapp that has "infobar" that spans the entire width of the webapp.  It's in the DEFAULT.aspx page because I want this infobar on top and showing at all times no matter where else the end-user will be in the webapp.  This infobar will show updates, statuses and what not.
It works by reading a table in a database, pulling the message and a style (red, yellow, green background).  When there is nothing to report, it disappears.  Below is a sample of what it looks like.

[image: Sample infobar screenshot]

For the most part this all works great!  I update the table via a UI.  My problem is this.  I want the infobar to update without the end user hitting F5 (which fires off code to pull the data).  So if I update the table, the timer, which runs once every 5 minutes (or whatever) looks to see if there is a value in the table.  If so, grab it and post it to the screen.  The update only works if the end user hits F5.
Below is my HTML code:

```
 <div>
          <asp:UpdatePanel ID="uppInfoBar" runat="server">
              <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Timer id="tmrInfoBar" runat="server" Interval="30000" OnTick="tmrInfoBar_Tick" Enabled="true" />
                <asp:Label runat="server" id="lblinfoBar" Visible="true"  >
                    <div class="info-bar" >
                        <div class="info-bar__wrapper">
                            <i data-info-bar="icon"></i>
                            <span id="spnInfoBar" runat="server" data-info-bar="text"></span>
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdf_Test" runat="server"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </asp:Label>
              </ContentTemplate>
          </asp:UpdatePanel>    
      </div>
```

When I step through my C# code, all the values are being pulled correctly, but the next step after the last "}" in my C# code, the infobar disappears.  There are no parameters switching it off anywhere in the project. 
If I comment out the timer, run everything it, update the table with a new message, hit F5, the updated message shows up.

What can I do to force an update\refresh to get the infobar to update on its own?  And I'm open to other suggestions on how this could be implemented.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to accomplish this, one would be to use `javascript` on the client side and use `setInterval` to perform an `ajax` call every xx seconds and get any new notifications, with the newer technology you could look into `SignalR` so that your server can push messages to the client, documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr)

Comment: I was hoping to avoid introducing another framework, plus I'm not all that familiar with it.  But I'll give it a go.  Hopefully come up with something that I can use universally.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: @JohnWaclawski You're quite welcome. I hope it helps.

Comment: I'm toying with that sample chat sample provided in the tutorial.  I'm thinking I may be able to even implement something as simple as that, as a "one-way" chat.  It populates the DIV with whatever I type into the text box similar to the example.
I'll let you know how it goes.